# Setting up a Django Site offline

Tags: python, django

I've copied a website from the server and trying to set it up offline however when I try `python manage.py syncdb` I get this error:

`TypeError: 'autocommit' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`
Anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: Please post the full traceback/error

Comment: That's the full error

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you have different versions of Django in your server and in your local environment. In Django 1.6 the `autocommit` option was introduced in order to disable it (by default it's `True`). https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#autocommit

You can:

- Upgrade the version of your python in your local to Django 1.6 or higher.
- If you have `autocommit: True` in your **settings.py** file just remove this line because by default it is `True`.